# polkadot canvas testnet contract deploy error "contracts.contractTrapped"

Tags: substrate, polkadot, rust-ink

I'm trying to deploy basic erc20 example contract on rococo canvas but "contracts.ContractTrapped" error popped on deployment? any hint will be much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Hey, would you be so kind as to repost this great question (with more details) on https://substrate.stackexchange.com/ -- and @Alejandro Martínez over there?
Very happy to assist on our shiny new Substrate (and friends) home for your questions!

Answer (score 1):

> A common source of `ContractTrapped` are Integer overflows, those can cause your contract to trap as well.

Please, check the [source](https://github.com/paritytech/ink-docs/blob/master/docs/faq/faq.md#why-am-i-getting-a-contracttrapped-error-when-interacting-with-a-contract) of this paragraph to see if it solves your issue.

Comment: Note Solidity checks for overflows since version 0.8 and SafeMath is not required.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the issue `ContractTrapped` while I wanted to add values in Solidity code **without** SafeMath library. The solution was to ensure safety of a source code like:

```
function sum(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a + b;
    require(c >= a);
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to declare `require(b >= 0)` as first line within this method?

Comment: Why? Please explain.

Comment: Because it's easier to understand. Does it not solve the `ContractTrapped` issue anymore then?

Comment: https://github.com/ConsenSysMesh/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol#L43

Comment: Ah, I see, my comment about making more sense doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: ..but curiosity is good, trying to improve things is also good, thanks for the comment, have a good day! ;-)